# Deleting large number of rows in chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 8 tables that have 10 million rows or more each and I want to do the fastest/elegant delete on them. I have decided to delete them in chunks at a time. When I added my changes, it looks very very ugly, and want to know how to format it to look better. Also, is this the best way to be doing this?

```
DECLARE @ChunkSize int
SET @ChunkSize = 50000

WHILE @ChunkSize <> 0
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize) FROM TABLE1
  WHERE CREATED < @DATE
     SET @ChunkSize = @@rowcount
END


DECLARE @ChunkSize int
SET @ChunkSize = 50000

WHILE @ChunkSize <> 0
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize) FROM TABLE2
  WHERE CREATED < @DATE
     SET @ChunkSize = @@rowcount
END
.......
```

I would be doing this for all 8 tables which doesn't seem practical. Any advice on how to clean this up?

Comment: for huge tables, you have to use partitioning and partition switching. this is not the right way to do.

Comment: Or you can save the data you want to keep to a new table, truncate the old tables, and re-insert back into them.

Comment: Until 2016 SP1 table partitioning was only available with Enterprise.

Comment: I initially tried @GordonLinoff's idea. But I need to keep track of what is being done in-case something goes wrong and I need to rollback.

Comment: Do a variation of @GordonLinoff's idea.  Put all the data into new tables, truncate the old ones, and put back only the data you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to 2016 SP1 when partitioning is only available in Enterprise you can either delete in batches or if the amount of data to be removed is small compared to the total data you can copy the good data to another table.

For doing the batch work I would make some suggestions to your code so it is a bit simpler.

```
DECLARE @ChunkSize int
SELECT @ChunkSize = 50000 --use select instead of set so @@rowcount will <> 0

WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize) FROM TABLE1
  WHERE CREATED < @DATE
END

SELECT @ChunkSize = @ChunkSize --this will ensure that @@rowcount = 1 again.

WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize) FROM TABLE2
  WHERE CREATED < @DATE
END
```

You may have to play with the ChunkSize to work well with your data but 50k is a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid repeating your loop for each table, you could use dynamic SQL

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb..#tableNames

SELECT name INTO #tableNames FROM sys.tables WHERE name IN (/* Names of tables you want to delete from */)

DECLARE @table varchar(50)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

WHILE EXISTS (select '1' from #tableNames)
BEGIN

SET @table = (select top 1 name from #tableNames)
DELETE FROM #tableNames WHERE name = @table

SET @query = 'DECLARE @ChunkSize int
              SET @ChunkSize = 50000

              WHILE @ChunkSize <> 0
              BEGIN
                DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize) FROM ' + @table + '
                WHERE CREATED < @DATE
                   SET @ChunkSize = @@rowcount
              END'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
END
```